# Sorting in Ruby by conditions

Tags: ruby, sorting, decimal, bit

I have this array:

```
arr = [3, 8, 2, 13, 7]
```

I need to sort the elements first by the number of 1's of their bits and then by the decimal:

```
bits | decimal
-----+--------
  10 |       2
  11 |       3
0001 |       8
 111 |       7
1011 |      13
```

to get the result:

```
[2, 3, 8, 7, 13]
```

I have this code:

```
arr = arr.sort { |x, y| x <=> y }
arr = arr.sort { |x, y| x.to_s(2).count(?1) <=> y.to_s(2).count(?1) }
arr # => [2, 8, 3, 13, 7]
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "first sort by 1's of your bits"? And under what system is `0001` equal to decimal `8`?

Comment: @moveson I'm pretty sure that's a typo for `1000`.

Comment: Do you mean "sort by 1s" as in "sort by *number of* 1s"? You're trying to define tie-breaker code here, but numerically the only way these values tie is if they're equivalent, making the tie-breaker irrelevant.

Comment: @tadman exactly, sort by number of 1's. Actually in OSX system this code above working well, but in Windows System that I trying, doesn't working.

Comment: Why should 3 come before 8? It has **more** 1's.

Comment: Also, what do you mean with "by the decimal"? Decimal is a representation, a string, so 13 should come before 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr.sort_by { |item| [item.to_s(2).count(?1), item] }
# => [2, 8, 3, 7, 13]
```

This contradicts the stated desired output, but I believe is consistent with the description of the problem (and that the stated desired output is incorrect): 2, 8 have 1 bit each, 3 has 2, 7 and 13 have 3 bits each; 2 comes before 8, 7 before 13.

This works because the default comparator for arrays is to compare them elementwise; e.g. for `2` and `8`, the comparator is seeing `[1, 2] <=> [1, 8]`; since the first element is same, the second element is compared as a tiebreaker.

I took "decimal" to mean "the numeric value", as represented in OP's code; if it is to be taken literally as "the decimal representation", then

```
arr.sort_by { |item| [item.to_s(2).count(?1), item.to_s] }
# => [2, 8, 3, 13, 7]
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann: The "desired result" is contradictory to the problem statement, as noted by yourself.

Comment: Ok :-). Btw I agree that your first solution is probably what he wants (I had already written the same, along with a snarky comment ridiculing how it's pretty much literally a piece-by-piece translation of his sentence "**sort** the elements first **by** the **number of 1's of their bits** and then by the **decimal**" and was just waiting for him to acknowledge/fix his errors before I was going to post it...)

Comment: `arr.sort_by { |item| [item.digits(2).count(1), items] }` is an alternative.

Comment: It seems odd sorting by alphabetical for the number. `10, 11, 100, 2`?

Comment: @Amadan thank you for your solution, this is what I needed. Sorry everyone by my bad question!